# Retrieve multiple values using ajax and php, without Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Website coding surely is awesome and I recently rialized that JavaScript and Ajax are really essential elements in order to build a outstanting website. I've done the research on internet, but the results weren't that useful. Every code included Jquery, which I don't comprehend. Also JSON is slightly unclear regarding the objects, etc.

W3schools published a few examples on how to generate an Ajax code that reacts with a PHP file. This data is retrieved through 'resonseText'. However this element only retrieves one unselected PHP string.

Is there a method to select specific variables or values from the PHP file and accordingly send it back to the Javascript (Ajax) file, so I can subsequently utilize them for further Javascript coding.

Thank you in advance. (It would greatly help, since Ajax is such a complex form of JavaScript.)

My Ajax code, to send data to the PHP file

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest() ;

        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") ;

        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                var XMLResponse = this.responseText ;

                document.getElementById("nameInputNote").innerHTML = "Status: " + XMLResponse ;

            }

        } ;

        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxIndex.php?rq1="+valueNameInput,true) ;
        xmlhttp.send() ;
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php

$rq1 = $_GET['rq1'] ;

if (empty($rq1) ) {

} else {

    $sql1 = "SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userName = '{$rq1}' " ;

    if ($result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) ) {

        $resultsSql1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1) ;

        if ($resultsSql1 == 0) {

            echo "vacant" ; //select this value with JS

            $permission = "true" ; //and select this value separately with JS

        } else {

            echo "occupied" ; // or in this senario: select this value

            $permission = "false" ; // and this value

// In this case the $permission variable is needed to determine whether a form should be submitted or not. 

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `Website coding surely is awesome` the novelty will wear off....

Comment: `echo json_encode(['vacant', 'true']);` or `echo json_encode(['occupied', 'false']);` then use `JSON.parse()` in JS.

Comment: FYI `ajax` is with jquery. hence `$.ajax` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
let src = <?php echo json_encode($yourVar); ?>;
```

And then use that variable. Other ways you can do that is to use axios, cookie or VueJS and pass data into component. Hope that helps.